# how to design a windows appication using c# to execute command line from lightscribe?

Tags: c#

hI Guys,

Do you all have any idea on how to design a windows appication using c# to execute command line from lightscribe? any help would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

To run an external process use `System.Diagnostics.Process` like this:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "a b c";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx